# Laravel - Redirect user after login to specific page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to redirect the user to the edit.blade page when they login for the first time. for this I made this code, but it doesn't work and i have no idea what the problem is. Can someone help me.

this is the code that I have now:

```
// This section is the only change
if ($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request))) {
    $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();
    // Make sure the user is active
    if ($user->verified && $this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        if ($user->first_time_login == true || $user->first_time_login == 1) {
            $this->redirectTo = '/users/edit';
            $user->first_time_login = false;
            $user->save();
        }
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

everything works except this line:

```
if ($user->first_time_login == true || $user->first_time_login == 1) {
    $this->redirectTo = '/users/edit';
}
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript

Comment: It's also not an `if/else` statement.  Please update the question and include a **[mcve]**

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message? Does it not work correctly? Does it redirect when it shouldn't, or vice versa?

Comment: no i don't get a error message, the redirect doesn't work at all, it only works when i add dd($user) in the code -> refresh the page -> delete dd($user) from the code-> and refresh the page then i get redirected to the right page but when i try it again after that it doesn't work anymore

Comment: and at the moment it works it works with false and true so that's also wrong @JJJ

Comment: Just a note, but the redirect should likely happen after everything else is done. Otherwise you may be exiting the script before you change the property first_time_login and you might not be doing $user->save(); If it's somehow asynchronous it may not matter.

Comment: thanks for the note, but the line $user->save(); works perfect, so i think that doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, i had to add `return redirect()->to('/users/edit');` on the bottom of the auth function that $this->redirrectTo is the default if the user has not already navigated to a different authed route.

My code now looks like this:

```
if ($user->first_time_login == true || $user->first_time_login == 1) {
                $this->redirectTo = '/users/edit';
                $user->first_time_login = false;
                $user->save();
                return redirect()->to('/users/edit');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `redirectTo` property or the `authenticated` method:

**redirectTo property:** [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-routing)

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a
>   redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->first_time_login){
        $user->first_time_login = false;
        $user->save();

        return '/users/edit';
    }else{
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

**authenticated method:**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->first_time_login) {
        $url = '/users/edit';
        $user->first_time_login = false;
        $user->save();
    } else {
        $url = $this->redirectTo;
    }

    return redirect($url);
}
```